# copy_from_user fails to copy data from userspace to a kernel buffer

Tags: linux, copy, kernel, arm, buffer

I am trying to copy a buffer from userspace into kernelspace. The

In userspace (code simplified):

```
int user_write (){
int64_t *decoded_buffer = (int64_t *)malloc(decoded_buffer_size_bytes) ;

<fill the buffer>

write(file_description, (void *)decoded_buffer, decoded_buffer_size_bytes);
free(decoded_buffer);
return 0;
}
```

in kernelspace (code simplified):

```
static ssize_t gpio_write(struct file *file, 
                          const char *buffer, 
                          size_t size, 
                          loff_t *offset)
{
    ssize_t result;
    //int counter;  
    int *kernelspace_buffer = (int *)kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);

    result = copy_from_user(kernelspace_buffer, buffer, size);  
    if (result) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "copy_from_user failed, returned: %d\n.", result);
        return -EINVAL; 
    }

    result = driver_write(kernelspace_buffer, size);
    kfree((void *)kernelspace_buffer);        
    return result;
}
```

I have been filling decoded_buffer with 65536 bytes of data and trying to write. Each time I write, copy_from_user fails and returns 63648 (meaning only 1888 bytes were copied). I've tried 
with different sized buffers and copy_from_user always fails (returning different values for different sized buffers).. What am I doing wrong with copy_from_user ?

I'm running on linux 2.6.39.4 an ARM9 processor.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to call it again to get remaining data? possibly in a while loop?

Comment: As I understand it, I pass it the buffer from userspace and the size of the buffer, and it should copy 'size' bytes into the kernelspace buffer. Then it returns the amount of bytes not copied (so on success, that'd be 0)

Comment: what is buffer? how do you get it? I'm sure you can find lots of examples on the web.

Comment: Buffer is passed from the userspace code. It is initialized in userspace as an int64_t buffer. But this is irrelevant, the kernel sees it as a char* argument. I know how to use copy_from_user generally. This is a case in which it's not working as I've normally seen and I'm unsure why.

Comment: The argument *buffer in kernelspace corresponds to decoded_buffer in userspace. It's passed via the write system call.